# How to define a PHP class for handling MySQL's "foreign key constraint" exception?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I'm rather new to PHP, and I want to:

1. define a class in the main directory of my web application and use it in sub-directories.
2. the class receives MySQL delete statements, executes them and catches foreign key constraint exception.

This is the class so far:

```
class MySQLErrorHandling
    {
        public function query($query_string)
            {
                try 
                   {
                      $conn = mysql_query($query_string);

                      if (!$conn) 
                      throw new Exception("mysql Error:");
                   } 
                catch(Exception $e) 
                   {
                      echo $e->getMessage(). mysql_error();
                   }
            }
    }
```

Any suggestions? 
Appreciated.

Comment: A class just for delete statements? Why that?

Comment: I think you should provide some code, we *won't make the work* for you, **we'll help with your work**. If you have a basic idea, write something. You'll need to include your class in all file where you use it (or build a layer that will provide include functionality).

Comment: Please stop using the ancient mysql_ functions. Use [PDO](http://us.php.net/pdo) instead, it has a [built-in way to throw exceptions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) in SQL error situations.

Comment: Thanks DCOder. I didn't know about PDO. I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than catching foreign key constraint exceptions I've suggest modeling your database with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Database will take care of proper deletion of items. Look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)
.

Comment: I think he wants to detect where the constraint **block** the delete sql, so he doesn't want to use CASCADE.

Comment: yes,  and I want to show a proper message why the record is not deleted form the DB.